# Exception in thread "main" org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, scribe

While running example of scribe to login with google it is showing following error.
I am using scribe-1.3.1.jar file.
Please tell me how to resolve it.

code is:

```
import org.scribe.builder.*;
import org.scribe.builder.api.*;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.*;

public class googleOaoth {

    private static final String NETWORK_NAME = "Google";
    private static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token=";
    private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/";
    private static final String SCOPE = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(GoogleApi.class).apiKey("Mykey").apiSecret("MySecret").scope(SCOPE).build();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("=== " + NETWORK_NAME + "'s OAuth Workflow ===");
        System.out.println();

        // Obtain the Request Token
        System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
        Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
        System.out.println("Got the Request Token!");
        System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + requestToken + " )");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
        System.out.println(AUTHORIZE_URL + requestToken.getToken());
        System.out.println("And paste the verifier here");
        System.out.print(">>");
        Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println();

        // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
        System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
        Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
        System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
        System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");
        System.out.println();

        // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
        System.out.println("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        request.addHeader("GData-Version", "3.0");
        Response response = request.send();
        System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(response.getCode());
        System.out.println(response.getBody());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thats it man! Go and build something awesome with Scribe! :)");

    }
}
```

after running above code

```
=== Google's OAuth Workflow ===

Fetching the Request Token...

Exception in thread "main" org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is     incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Timestamp is too far from current time: 1353931608

    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:41)
    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:27)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:52)
    at action.login.googleOaoth.main(googleOaoth.java:34)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Is the clock on your computer correct?  The timestamp `1353931608` suggests that your local time is `Fri Jan 16 17:05:31 GMT 1970`.  Current time would have a timestamp around 1000 times bigger...

Comment: @beny23 can you please answer the question so the OP can mark it as accepted? trying to close all unanswered scribe questions on stack overflow. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was initially just a comment:

Is the clock on your computer correct? The timestamp `1353931608` suggests that your local time is `Fri Jan 16 17:05:31 GMT 1970`. Current time would have a timestamp around 1000 times bigger...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your server time is not correctly set. Please correct your server time, you may want to restart your web server after fixing the time.
 - Change Server time.  Try restart Webserver first. If not work, restart your Computer ==> it work! .